# How to parse huge JSON files in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, json, swift

This is what I have now:

- 4 JSON files
- ~ 2 000 000 lines in each file
- ~ 250MB each file

  ```
  if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "file_1", ofType: "json") {

      let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

      do {

          let data = try Data(contentsOf: url, options: Data.ReadingOptions.mappedIfSafe)

          do {

              if let results = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? Array<[AnyHashable: Any]> {
                  //do something here with that
              }

          } catch {
              print("error1: \(error)")
          }

      } catch {
          print("error2: \(error)")
      }
  }
  ```

But all I have is an error:

> Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue

Is it possible at all to parse that 4 json files using iphone in Swift? I need to parse it within a few seconds.

Comment: Do you have to keep all theses data in RAM?

Comment: for the error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19203790/is-it-possible-to-debug-terminated-due-to-memory-error

you want to parse 4 json file at once? if yes, do you keep put in a directory?

Comment: I do not have to keep them in RAM. All I need to do is to parse them, count the values for some "key", and display them. That is all.

Comment: phone is not made for that kind of work i'm afraid

Comment: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29440325/parsing-continuous-json-stream-in-ios) can help so you dont have to load the whole file

Comment: Did you find solution for this issue? If so please post it so It can help. Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this library: https://github.com/postmates/PMJSON.

I don't try it yet, but seems a possible solution.

Sorry for my English.

Comment: Is it suitable for these large files, I don't see any mention about that in the read me.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
let data = try Data(contentsOf: url, options: Data.ReadingOptions.mappedIfSafe)
```

uses about 250MB of memory. That is a huge amount for an app. Especially if you load 4 files. You memory usage is about 1GB. So in two words - it's impossible. You need to find a better solution to your problem.

Comment: I think that's what he's asking for, isn't it?

Comment: @VinceO'Sullivan, he's asking if it's possible (_Is it possible at all to parse that 4 json files using iphone in Swift?_). The answer is **NO**.

Comment: The answer is yes, but he'll have to stream them.

Comment: speak with the backend guys and download in chunks

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5.1**
Use below code for **huge JSON** file. It works for me.

```html
    func readJSONFromFile(fileName: String) -> Any?
    {
        var json: Any?
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: "json") {
            do {
                let fileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
                // Getting data from JSON file using the file URL
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileUrl, options: .mappedIfSafe)
                json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)
                print(json)
            } catch {
                // Handle error here
            }
        }
        return json
    }
```